# Segfault due to static linking with ocaml and c libraries

Tags: segmentation-fault, ocaml, z3, static-linking, libc

I have a question regarding static linking in ocaml. When passing the flag "-static" to the c compiler, it compiles but when calling the resulting binary I immediately get a segmentation fault. The output of gdb is the following:

```
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x000000000052268e in _GLOBAL__sub_I_util.cpp ()
#2  0x0000000001a5a00c in __libc_csu_init ()
#3  0x0000000001a597d7 in __libc_start_main ()
#4  0x000000000053505a in _start ()
```

When I compile without static linking everything works fine. However, I need a static binary for benchmarking on an external server. 
I already tried to use ocaml together with musl but unfortunately, the installation process fails due to the following unresolved [issue](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/issues/9131).

Did anybody encounter the same problem and knows how to solve this problem?

Update: It took us sometime but we found out that the problem seems to be related to the smt solver z3. An MWE is

Source file (checks whether the formula "true" is satisfiable)

```
module Z3Solver =
  struct
    let context = ref (
                      Z3.mk_context [
                          ("model", "true");
                          ("proof", "false");
                        ]
                    )   
    let satis  =
      let z3_expr = Z3.Boolean.mk_true !context in
      let optimisation_goal = Z3.Optimize.mk_opt !context in
      Z3.Optimize.add optimisation_goal [z3_expr];
      let status = Z3.Optimize.check optimisation_goal in
      status == Z3.Solver.SATISFIABLE
  end

let run =
  let model = Z3Solver.satis in
  if model then
    print_string "satisfiable\n"
  else 
    print_string "unsatisfiable\n"
```

We use OMake to compile this program into a static native binary.

```
USE_OCAMLFIND = true
OCAMLOPTFLAGS += -p -g -thread -ccopt -static -cc $(CXX)

OCAMLPACKS[] =
    z3

# Include all .ml files
FILES[] = $(removesuffix .ml, $(glob *.ml))

.PHONY: clean install

.DEFAULT: install

OCamlProgram(z3test, $(FILES))

install: z3test

clean:
    rm -f \
     *.cmi \
         *.cmx \
         *.o \
     *.omc \
     *.log \
     *.cache \
     z3test z3test.opt \
```

The OMakeroot file is just the standard OMakeroot file. The OCaML version is 4.07.1, the z3 version is 4.8.7.

Comment: Looking at your stack I see something that looks like C++ initialization. If you really are just linking with C that could be something to look into. It would also help if you gave a complete, small example that shows the problem. There's very little to go on in your description of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I included an MWE.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, linking the z3 static library to make a static-linked binary (written in C++). However, it is very strange, if I choose to make a dynamic-linked binary (but still link against z3 static library, libz3.a), there is no problem. I'm still investigating why.

Answer (score 0):

> Did anybody encounter the same problem

One possible explanation: your binary is too big, the linker has relocation overflow, but either doesn't warn about it, or you ignored the warning.

To confirm that this is the case, examine your binary with `ls -l` -- if it's over 2GiB in size, relocaition overflow is likely.

Also make sure there is no link warning, and that your linker is recent.

> how to solve this problem?

If the problem is in fact due to relocation overflow, there isn't much you can do -- your binary is too large.

If you built it (or some parts of it) without optimization, try building with optimization (that can produce significantly smaller binaries), and/or build with `-ffunction-sections` `-fdata-sections` and `-Wl,--icf=safe` to enable linker garbage collection.

If none of that works, you may try to build and link everything with `-mcmodel=large`, but that is not a well-tested configuration, and may fail for a different reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a z3 issue.
If you configure z3 this way: `./configure --staticlib --single-threaded` and then compile it to get libz3.a (I also delete the old `build` directory before `configure`), I think it might work.

I'm raising this issue to the developers, see also: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/4554

Thanks!